# How do I remove comments from an existing webform?

Tags: forms, webforms, comments

After the fact, I learned how to make comments `<hidden>` by default for new webforms. However, for the forms I've already created, there is no option to remove comments. How do I remove comments for these already published forms? Do I have to make a whole new form, or edit the database directly somehow?

Thanks for any help, and please let me know if there is any other information I need to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do either; you can edit any existing webform and toggle the `Comment settings` menu to `Hidden` on each published form.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to delete those comments you could build a View and include a Views Bulk Operations field and then using filters find all comments of nodes of type Webform, and bulk delete them

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all the comments on that node. There might be a lot of comments in lots of webforms. So to make your task easy follow below steps:

1. Download module [admin_views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) and enable it.
2. Go to `admin/content/comment` and run a search based on the title of the node, then delete all the comments. See in image [image]